# Access object created in innerClass from elsewhere java

Tags: java, object, inner-classes, outer-classes

so i have outerClass and innerClass, and i want to access the object created from innerClass using outerClass, example:

```
public Class outerClass{
    Class innerClass{
        //properties
    }
}
```

so what i want to do is something like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        outerClass outerObj = new outerClass();
        outerClass.innerClass innerObj = outerObj.new innerClass();

        //this is what i want:
        outerObj.innerObj;
    }
}
```

it might be complicated but what i want to do is get the innerObject, using only outerObject

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: line below comment doesnt work

Comment: Create innerObj in your outerClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Class outerClass{
    Class innerClass{
        //properties
    }

    public innerClass innerObj;
}

outerObj.innerObj = outerClass.new innerClass();
```

Comment: yes that's the solution i came up with but is there any easier way?

Comment: @nikagar4 What do you mean by easier ?

Comment: To be able to perform `outerObj.innerObj` there is no other way

Comment: is there a way to do that without that extra property called "innerObj"?

Comment: @nikagar4 Then you shouldn't say `and i want to access the object created from innerClass using outerClass`. Create a separate class.

Comment: this is the best solution in my opinion so ill stick with this

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
public class outerClass{
    public static class innerClass{
        //properties
    }
}
```

Comment: I thnk it is a valid answer

Answer (score 1):

```
outerClass.innerClass innerObj = outerObj.new innerClass();
```

`innerObj` is a local variable. You can refer to it directly as

```
innerObj
```

Comment: i want to access it from another class

Comment: Then you'd need to pass it to the other class. It's just a plain old local variable. `outerObj` doesn't keep a hold of a reference to `innerObj` (but `innerObj` *does* keep hold of a reference to `outerObj`).

Comment: yes i understand but i wanted to be able to access it using only outerClass

Comment: @nikagar4 then you don't understand. You can't access it using only `outerClass` because `outerClass` (or `outerObj`) doesn't keep a reference to `innerObj`, unless you actually add a reference to the instance to the outer class, like Nadir suggests.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-static inner class, the compiler automatically adds a hidden reference to the "owner" object instance. When you try to create it from a static method (say, the main method), there is no owning instance. It is like trying to call an instance method from a static method - the compiler won't allow it, because you don't actually have an instance to call.

So the inner class must either itself be static (in which case no owning instance is required), or you only create the inner class instance from within a non-static context.

So make your innerClass `static`

```
public static class innerClass{
        //properties
    }
```

You can call

```
outerClass.innerClass innerObj = new outerClass.innerClass();
```

If you want to access fields only via dot(.) notation should consider using

static inner field in your outerClass like a PrintStream  in System class

Example:

```
public class outerClass{
    public static innerClass innerObject = new innerClass();
    static  class  innerClass{
            //properties
        }
    }
```

and then in main method

```
outerClass outerClass= new outerClass();
        outerClass.innerObject.yourfied
```